# Why does the composition of Ocean Water list sodium and chloride separately?

Tags: aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry, ions

[This](http://glossary.periodni.com/glossary.php?en=composition%20of%20ocean%20water) is the site I am using.

It is also found [here](http://www.lenntech.com/composition-seawater.htm), but this uses mg/L instead of percents.

It lists Sodium at 30.8%, and Chloride at 55.3%. How can this be? Shouldn't the two be listed as Sodium Chloride or salt? Because as far as I know, there is no way to obtain chloride on its own.

Comment: It's not like they just float there in the form of $\ce{NaCl}$, either.

Comment: @IvanNeretin What do you mean

Comment: Forget it. Let's put it this way: yes, these two could be listed together as $\ce{NaCl}$, but the authors chose otherwise. This is entirely legitimate and meaningful, even though you can't isolate $\ce{Cl-}$ on its own.

Comment: Giving a NaCl content is nonsense. If you had put together the numbers, you would've found they don't match.  55.3 g / 35.4 (g/mol) = 1.5 chloride, 30.8 / 23 (g/mol) = 1.3 sodium. There are a lot of other ions in the sea, with magnesium and sulfate making up most of the difference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawater#Origin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, of course you could provide NaCl content as a weight or molar percentage, and I can demonstrate if necessary.

However, this doesn't really reflect the reality: ocean water is a solution of many salts. Chloride does not necessarily only come from NaCl, but can also come from KCl, MgCl$_2$, and so on. All the ions are solved individually, and if you start evaporating the water, you will get a mix of salts.

So there's really no point in showing NaCl percentage.

Of course, you're right in that it is impossible to obtain pure chloride ions. But the chlorides you *will* obtain will not necessarily be those of sodium.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway I can find somewhere where it lists it as NaCl and MgCl2, etc

Comment: @SuperNinja741DoesGaming Do you mean like a brand of water, or are you interested in the calculation? I'm not sure what you are asking about.

Comment: still for ocean water

Comment: @SuperNinja741DoesGaming sorry for the late answer, I was away... here's the thing - if you want the composition listed in compounds rather than ions (i.e. NaCl - x g/L instead of Na+ - y g/L, Cl- - z g/L), then that might depend on the way the sea water is evaporated, and will very much depend on what sea water we are talking about (concentrations differ a lot). I've found this paper http://jsedres.sepmonline.org/content/57/5/928.full.pdf+html , but can't access it at the moment. It may contain what you are interested in.

Comment: @SuperNinja741DoesGaming Also, there's this http://www.hydrochemistry.eu/exmpls/sea_evap.html  , but I'm not sure if that helps. Sorry for not having a better answer. I can, of course, show how to calculate the THEORETICAL MAXIMUM of NaCl in a certain sea water, but I'm not sure if that would actually precipitate in reality. Let me know if you are still interested.